# oracle sql loader validate only

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sql-loader

I use Sql Loader with Oracle 10g.
My problem : i want to validate my data file before insertions in database.
Is it possible ? 
Because, if there are errors in my datafile (bad fields length for example), the table MUST NOT BE ERASED. (control file is in REPLACE mode).
I dont need transactions. I only ask if it's possible to sqlldr to verify/validate date file before begin insertions ?

I find it a shame to have to rewrite a script to control the data file before processing ...

Thank a lot.

Simon

Comment: I'd use an external table with all fields as varchar instead of SQL Loader. This way, you can check field lengths / data types inside the database, and only if all checks are successful, you can copy the data into your target table.

Comment: Or, slightly closer to the current workflow, load the data into a staging table, do the validations, and only then load into the real table.